# How would I know if getty spawn shell process with my id?

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel

Assuming that I have a system call hooking for "exec(vc)" and "exit".

Then, how can I know if the shell with my login id is being executed and being exited in the hooking routine?

How I can check if "exec" is for the shell? Further, how I know if the login id for shell is mine?

On the other hand, when the shell exits, how the "exit" hooking function knows if the the login id for shell was mine?